# Saving Deployment settings between machines when project is stored on mounted drive

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I use PHPStorm to manage several applications which are stored on a network mounted drive. Each application has its own "Default Remote Host"s.

I also alternate between the office and home every other day.

Now, everytime I load up a project in PHPStorm, I'm required to review my deployment settings, and set the default remote host back. Along with this, I also have to re-enter the information on the Mappings Tab of the Deployment dialog.

I'd love a way to, well, not have to do this every day.

Any way around this?

Comment: Sync your `webServers.xml` (at very least shared entries) between all involved computers: 1) http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5502649#5502649 2) http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5476232#5476232 ...

Comment: As of today (**7.1** EAP is now available) this sync should be not necessary any more -- deployment settings should now be matched by Deployment name rather than hidden unique IDs (I do not have 100% confirmation  since I do not have such setup, but that's how it should now work)